# Change input to a smaller range

Tags: arduino

First time poster here so please go easy on me? :)

I'm currently playing around with a Teensy 3.1 Arduino compatible board, just to see what I can do with the thing. So I currently have some code that I found that basically just emulates a keyboard and types in 0000 ENTER, 0001 ENTER, all the way to 9999.

I want to adjust the code so I can change the ranges to what ever I like, so for example starting from 2000-3000 or 2500-2600, etc.  If someone could tell me what lines need to be adjusted to achieve that, I'll be very thankful.

```
    #include <usb_keyboard.h>
// This code is licensed under Apache 2.0 License
// http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
// Limitation of Liability. In no event and under no legal theory,
// whether in tort (including negligence), contract, or otherwise,
// unless required by applicable law (such as deliberate and grossly
// negligent acts) or agreed to in writing, shall any Contributor be
// liable to You for damages, including any direct, indirect, special,
// incidental, or consequential damages of any character arising as a
// result of this License or out of the use or inability to use the
// Work (including but not limited to damages for loss of goodwill,
// work stoppage, computer failure or malfunction, or any and all
// other commercial damages or losses), even if such Contributor
// has been advised of the possibility of such damages.
// This code is indented for people who are not able to contact
// apple support and I am in no way liable for any damage or
// problems this code might cause.

const int ledPin = 13; // choose the pin for the LED
int counter = 0;
int fakecounter = counter;
char pin[] = "xxxx";

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // declare LED as output
  delay(10000);
}

void loop() {
  keyboard_modifier_keys = 0;
  if (counter <= 9999) {
    delay(8000);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(5500);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    sprintf(pin, "%04d", fakecounter);
    //sending first digit
    Keyboard.press(pin[0]);
    delay(450);
    Keyboard.release(pin[0]);
    delay(420);
    //sending second digit
    Keyboard.press(pin[1]);
    delay(398);
    Keyboard.release(pin[1]);
    delay(510);
    //sending third digit
    Keyboard.press(pin[2]);
    delay(421);
    Keyboard.release(pin[2]);
    delay(423);
    //sending forth digit
    Keyboard.press(pin[3]);
    delay(430);
    Keyboard.release(pin[3]);
    delay(525);
    //sending enter
    Keyboard.press(KEY_ENTER);
    delay(305);
    Keyboard.release(KEY_ENTER);
  }
  //reached 4 digit PIN max value
  if (counter > 9999) {
    for (int blinkies = 0; blinkies < 8; blinkies++) {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      delay(20);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      delay(200);
    }
    delay(6000);
  }
  ++counter;
  fakecounter = counter;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be PHP.

Comment: Hi @kimlo, Welcome to stackoverflow! I suggest editing your tag based on the related topic like `arduino` so that other stack users that have knowledge in this area could help you! :)

Comment: Hello @kimlo, I've provided an answer, please see if you can understand it.

Comment: Hi @catzilla, thanks for the warm welcome. Sorry about the tag situation, first time poster (have stumbled past here hundreds of times though) so wasn't sure about what tags were available. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int counter = 0;` is the beginning and   `if (counter <= 9999) {` defines the end. Change 0 for your choice of beginning and 9999 for your choice of ending.

---

The code works because `keyboard.press` and `keyboard.release` accepts a character to select which key to press and release. It uses sprintf to get the value of `counter` to the char array `pin`, converting from int to string, using the value of the variable `fakecounter` as middleman. The value of counter is increased and it's typed in the virtual keyboard along with the enter key.

Comment: Hi Elric, thank you so much for your quick and thorough response. I'm a total coding noob (best I've done is a day or two of python back in a university course haha) but I believe what you've given me is exactly what I'm after. 

I'm trying to compile it on my Teensy 3.1 board using Arduino but I'm getting compiling errors. But it was working yesterday with the same code (except for the different numbers) and now my original code won't compile either. 

I'm going to un-install all Teensy/Arduino software and start fresh and see if I can get it to work using the information you've given me.

Comment: I didn't know it wasn't compiling. Can you post the errors?

Comment: I just un-installed everything Arduino and re-installed and it compiled and uploaded using the same code. So there was some weird program problem.

I made the suggested changes and it is indeed starting from 1000 and moving up by 1, so it's doing exactly what I wanted it to do!

Thank you so much Elric, you are such a great help, thank you!!!!

Question marked as solved.

Comment: Yey! Arduino is really rewarding when it works! glad I could help.